# What is unrefined sugar called?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, vocabulary

The definition of ‘unrefined’ is

> *not processed to remove impurities or unwanted elements.*

Several synonyms are also listed: *unprocessed, untreated, unpurified, crude, raw, natural, plain, coarse, rough, unworked, unprepared, unmilled, unfinished*

But what is **unrefined sugar** commonly called in English?
Is there a formal expression too?

Comment: _Raw_ or _brown_ sugar (brown due to presence of molasses)

Comment: "Turbinado" is another term that is used.

Comment: @NVZ: My understanding (but I could be wrong) is that raw sugar is the input to refining, and both white sugar and brown sugar (light or dark), plus molasses are outputs. IOW, brown sugar is white sugar plus some of the molasses that was taken out of the raw sugar. If this is so then whether raw sugar can be said to contain molasses is questionable: in a sense, yes, in another sense, no.

Comment: OMG. People who should know better still answering questions in comments. Why don't they follow the instructions not to do so?

Comment: @David "off topic" questions like these don't deserve a full answer, IMHO. These get closed and deleted anyway. A quick answer in comments will help the OP, so there's that.

Answer (score 2):

There are several terms referring to unrefined sugar, the most common ones being "*brown sugar*", "*raw sugar*" or sometimes "*cane sugar*". But you're probably rather looking for "*jaggery*", a yellowish stuff native to Asia and Africa allegedly providing special nutritional properties (still being debated).

Comment: +1 for a good answer. But I'd like to inform you that in most cases, such one-liner questions get closed and eventually deleted, and if that happens, answers are also automatically deleted.

Comment: Thanks NVZ. I understand that the question _per se_ may not be that relevant, but it's still a reasonable question and as such it's worth an answer, short-lived as it can be.

Answer (score 1):

Most sugar is at least partially refined.For example, you can go to your local supermarket and buy light brown sugar or dark brown sugar, but both have been refined. Here from Wikipedia are blurbs about two *unrefined* sugars.
"Panela (Spanish pronunciation: [paˈnela], Portuguese: rapadura [ʁɐpɐˈduɾɐ]) is unrefined whole cane sugar, typical of Central and of Latin America in general, which is a solid form of sucrose derived from the boiling and evaporation of sugarcane juice. ... Panela is also known as rapadura in Portuguese. Sucarat ( a contraction of "Sucre de canne naturel) is  a brand name for a variety of whole cane sugar..." If you are willing to settle for partially refined sugars here is a pretty good list of what's available for cooking. Sugars like maple sugar are not listed.http://www.thekitchn.com/whats-the-difference-muscovado-145157